# UVa Contest Scoreboard

Tags: java

I have been trying the [Contest Scoreboard problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1199) on UVA. The following code works fine for me on the sample input but gives runtime error when submitted to the judge. Could somebody help me out with pinpointing whats wrong ?
P.S. I did rename my class to Main before submitting.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class contestscoreboard_10258 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int count = 0;
        br.readLine();

        HashMap<Integer,contestant> contestants = new HashMap<Integer,contestant>();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(count<cases)
        {
            // Read blank line after each case
            String line = br.readLine();
            String [] params;
            while(!line.trim().equals(""))
            {
                params = line.split(" ");
                int contestant = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
                int problem = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                int time = Integer.parseInt(params[2]);
                char result = params[3].charAt(0);

                contestant c;
                if(contestants.containsKey(contestant))
                {
                    c = contestants.get(contestant);
                }
                else
                {
                    c = new contestant();
                    contestants.put(contestant, c);
                }

                if(!c.problems.contains(problem))
                {
                    // if its correct
                    if(result == 'C')
                    {
                        c.penalty = c.penalty + time;
                        c.problems.add(problem);
                        c.solved++;
                    }
                    else if(result == 'I')
                    {
                        c.penalty = c.penalty+20;
                    }
                }

                line = br.readLine();
                params = line.split(" ");
            }



            while(!contestants.isEmpty())
            {
                int max = getMaxKey(contestants);
                contestant c = contestants.get(max);
                sb.append(max+" "+c.solved+" "+c.penalty+"\n");
                contestants.remove(max);
            }
            sb.append("\n");

            count++;
        }

        System.out.print(sb.toString());

    }

    public static int getMaxKey(HashMap<Integer,contestant> contestants)
    {

        Iterator<Integer> keys = contestants.keySet().iterator();
        int max_solved = -1;
        int max_time = -1;
        int max_id = -1;
        while(keys.hasNext())
        {
            int key = keys.next();
            contestant c = contestants.get(key);
            if(c.solved>max_solved)
            {
                max_id = key;
                max_solved = c.solved;
                max_time = c.penalty;
            }
            else if(c.solved== max_solved)
            {
                if(c.penalty>max_time)
                {
                    max_id = key;
                    max_solved = c.solved;
                    max_time = c.penalty;
                }
                else if(c.penalty==max_time)
                {
                    if(key<max_id)
                    {
                        max_id = key;
                        max_solved = c.solved;
                        max_time = c.penalty;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        return max_id;      
    }
}

class contestant
{
    int solved;
    ArrayList<Integer> problems;
    int penalty;
    public contestant()
    {
        solved = 0;
        problems = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        penalty = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Online Judges never reveal the stack trace. Thats the issue. The code works fine on my machine and with the sample input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use `Public classes` in that online judge. See the `UVa Online Judge - Submission specification for Java` [here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30).

Comment: I have tried using them before and it works fine for me. I also tried removing it but it still didnt work. Of course I did rename my class to Main.

Comment: your code does not output the correct answers to the given test case. or am i wrong ?? I just run your code.

Comment: It works fine for me. Besides if that would have been the issue I would rather have got a "Wrong answer" verdict instead of a "Runtime Error" verdict. What output did you get for the test input from my code ?

Comment: Actually i had to change your code a little.I did not submit the answer to the Judge.Now I checked the input format. I think you are reading the inputs incorrectly. They have said that `there is also a blank line between two consecutive inputs.` But their sample input does not have the blank lines. Don't know why. 
I'll try this question and let you know.